# ggplot created in shiny app does not recognize column name

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am working on a shiny app that is supposed to enable the user to load data from an excel file and to create some graphs based on this data. To do this I use `read.xlsx` and `ggplot`. The user can select the x variable `input$x` and y variable `input$y` from a list. This list is created based on the column names of the data set. Based on the input a graph is created:

```
ggplot() +  geom_point(data=mydata, aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)
```

However, when some of the columns of my example dataset are chosen, I get an error. For instance, when i select the y variable to be equal to the `AB (m/s)`, I get the following error:

```
Error: could not find function "AB"
```

The `ggplot` somehow does not recognize the special characters and only takes the first part of the column name. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: The issue is that the variables contain space. If you cannot rename the columns (e.g. replace spaces with `_`) you can try with  `\``.  `\`x\`` may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the nice suggestion fra. Eventually i have solved it like this:

```
x<-paste0("`",input$x,"`")
y<-paste0("`",input$y,"`")
ggplot() +  geom_point(data=mydata, aes_string(x=x, y=y)
```